# Can ssh local but cannot from other computeres

Tags: server, ssh, firewall, openssh, sshd

My desktop is a Linux (Ubuntu) machine with ssh server configured. It used to work fine before I moved the desktop to a new network. Now I can ssh into the machine from itself (either by ssh localhost or ssh ).

However, I cannot ssh from another machine. It gets stuck at "Connecting to **** port ****" and then times out. I have tried to look for firewalls, but there are none. I have allowed ssh and the port in my ufw. Also, if I check "service iptables status" I get "not-found".

My /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts/deny are also fully commented out (i.e. no active filters). I can also ping to my desktop from my Macbook.

This seems to be a question discussed at multiple places online, but, even after spending several hours, I cannot find a solution. Can somebody please help me sort this out?

Comment: Firstly, `iptables` is not a service.  It's a frontend for netfilter in the kernel, you can't 'shut it off' like a normal service.  `iptables -L -n -v` will indicate rulesets.  If you mean 'another machine' as in external to your local network and via the Internet, the router needs to NAT / port forward for that stuff.

Comment: I see. I get a long list using iptables command. What rule should I be looking for? My desktop is connected to the LAN, and my Macbook is connected to wifi, but the network is the same.

Comment: I'd need to see your whole ruleset.  Paste the ruleset (or the output of `iptables-save`) into your question as an edit.

Comment: I was wrong, and I think what you suggested is correct. Although I was connected to the same "network", there is probably some difference. After I use the VPN to connect to the network, I can ssh fine. Thanks for your help anyway!